# Center content and image preloader

Tags: css

I am trying to get my preload spinner to center in the middle of the page and  get the image to center inside the spinner, the spinner seems to be to the right about 50px. Not sure why it seems to have a offset. I also want the logo not to spin inside

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
  $('.loaderInner').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
  $('#load_cover').delay(400).fadeOut('slow');  
  $('body').delay(400).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

```css
#load_cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1000000;
}

.loaderInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.loader-logo{
 background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/saki/nuoveXT/128/Small-arrow-down-icon.png');
}

.loader {
  border: 4px solid #838383;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 4px solid #dddddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.7s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 0.7s linear infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #999;
  filter: blur(0.9px);
  
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="load_cover">
  <div class="loaderInner">
    <div class="loader loader-logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your loader logo also has a height and width of 100px which
 causes a shift of loader logo from the center.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
  $('.loaderInner').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
  $('#load_cover').delay(400).fadeOut('slow');  
  $('body').delay(400).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

```css
#load_cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1000000;
}

.loaderInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loader-logo{
width: 100px;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
top: calc(50% - 38px);
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 70px);
height: 100px;
 background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/saki/nuoveXT/128/Small-arrow-down-icon.png');
}

.loader {
  border: 4px solid #838383;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 4px solid #dddddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.7s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 0.7s linear infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #999;
  filter: blur(0.9px);
  
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="load_cover">
  <div class="loaderInner">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader-logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any way to keep the image from spinning?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. You want spinning or not?

Comment: i want the spinner to spin but i dont want the image to spin

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: So you want the image at the center of spinner?

Answer (score 0):

use a transform property to fix the offset 
and use the logo as background and centered see your code below after edit.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
  $('.loaderInner').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
  $('#load_cover').delay(400).fadeOut('slow');  
  $('body').delay(400).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

```css
#load_cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1000000;
}

.loaderInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.loader {
  border: 4px solid #838383;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 4px solid #dddddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.7s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 0.7s linear infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #999;
  filter: blur(0.9px);
  background:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/saki/nuoveXT/128/Small-arrow-down-icon.png') no-repeat center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="load_cover">
  <div class="loaderInner">
    <div class="loader loader-logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```